# cannot able to read name attribute in json file

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({

        url: '/GisMap/GetLayers?layerName=All',
        type: "get",

        dataType:"json" ,

        success: function (data) {
            alert('Data received: ');
            var xmlDoc = data.result;
            console.log(xmlDoc.layers.layer[0].name);
            alert(xmlDoc.layers.layer[0].name);
```

Json data is coming from server, but I'm not able to read particular name attribute value. this is my Json data.

```
{"layers":{"layer":[{"name":"poly_landmarks","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/poly_landmarks.json"},{"name":"Img_Sample","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/Img_Sample.json"},{"name":"tasmania_cities","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_cities.json"},{"name":"tasmania_roads","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_roads.json"},{"name":"tasmania_state_boundaries","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_state_boundaries.json"},{"name":"tasmania_water_bodies","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_water_bodies.json"},{"name":"archsites","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/archsites.json"},{"name":"restricted","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/restricted.json"}]}}
```

Comment: i am getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer' of undefined
    at Object.success (map.js:48)
    at fire (jquery.js:3317)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3447)
    at done (jquery.js:9272)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9514)

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data); console.log(data.layers.layer[0].name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JSON.parse()`

```js
data = '{"layers":{"layer":[{"name":"poly_landmarks","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/poly_landmarks.json"},{"name":"Img_Sample","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/Img_Sample.json"},{"name":"tasmania_cities","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_cities.json"},{"name":"tasmania_roads","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_roads.json"},{"name":"tasmania_state_boundaries","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_state_boundaries.json"},{"name":"tasmania_water_bodies","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_water_bodies.json"},{"name":"archsites","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/archsites.json"},{"name":"restricted","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/restricted.json"}]}}';

  data = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(data.layers.layer[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var json = '{"layers":{"layer":[{"name":"poly_landmarks","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/poly_landmarks.json"},{"name":"Img_Sample","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/Img_Sample.json"},{"name":"tasmania_cities","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_cities.json"},{"name":"tasmania_roads","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_roads.json"},{"name":"tasmania_state_boundaries","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_state_boundaries.json"},{"name":"tasmania_water_bodies","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_water_bodies.json"},{"name":"archsites","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/archsites.json"},{"name":"restricted","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/restricted.json"}]}}';


var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
var foo = parsed.layers.layer;

for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + '. name: ' + foo[i].name + ', href: ' + foo[i].href);
}
```

And here's a [working example](https://repl.it/IfKr/2).